# How to allow a block on a page to load another block on same page in Drupal 7?

Tags: views, blocks

This is what I am looking for: On a page that has a block, I want the ability of a link within that block to load another block on the same page. (Specific case: a static page has a Views block containing a grid of team members with a 'see more' link under their picture. I want that link to load the user profile as a block, but on the same page - presumably this should use ajax).

Any help on how to do this would be supremely appreciated. Thanks.

Can't post images on Drupal.stackexchange yet but here are two screenshots to illustrate what I am looking to do: http://goo.gl/WBgcR

Comment: Which version are you using D7 or D6 ?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7 (just edited the title too)

Answer (score 0):

As i understood from your problem, i think you can benefit from this lesson
Ajax node reader in drupal
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyLmQtiSXgI

and there is a module called Ajax Blocks, can benefit u if u wnt to creat ur own module.

and as alternative solutions u can use
 http://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node
so the user profile loads in colorbox modal dialog

Comment: Thanks for your input. The first link is essentially about a slideshow, but the small images controlling the large one are still visible. I'm looking to replace them altogether. The second one, colorbox node, I'm familiar with but I need to keep the user on the same page and not use a pop-up. To my original question I attached two screenshots to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Hello did u find solution for your problem

Comment: No. I did a workaround which went from the block's link to a static page, so I wasn't able to achieve the ajax loading within the same page. The project is finished now but if I (or anyone else) has a solution for this, ideally it will get posted here.